# tvos UISegmentedControl focus style not change

Tags: ios, focus, highlight, uisegmentedcontrol, tvos

I want to change background color of UISegmentedControl when it highlighted in tvOS.

Normally Segment display like following.
[image]

When change focus for change selected segment at that time display like following.
[image]

> How to change white background when UISegmentedControl focused?

I was try following things but not working.

1) create custom class of UISegmentedControl and do following code in *awakeFromNib*

```
[self setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateFocused barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

2) override **setHighlighted** method of UISegmentedControl

3) change background color in **didUpdateFocusInContext** method.

Answer (score 2):

From my understanding of your question, you want to change the background color same as UISegmentControl tint color. What you need to do is simply use this:

```
label.backgroundColor = segmentedControl.tintColor;
```

Hope this will help you if not try this:

You just need to give its background color to clear from storyboard. This is happening due to default background selection and default selection is as per theme. Once you set the segmentControl background color to clear you will get the required result.

Or you can do:
Try to set your UISegmentcontrol background color to clear in viewDidLoad, you will get your result. I have tried this and it worked for me.

```
segment.backgroundColor = Color.clear;
```

Comment: It's not working. when Focus segmentControl at that time it display white overlay (default). I want to remove that white overlay from segment when it focused.

Comment: You tried all of the three solutions? Cause they worked for me

Answer (score 0):

its easy to clear the background color of segment control:

yourSegment.backgroundColor = .clear