# How to change white background when UISegmentedControl focused?

Tags: swift, tvos, uifocusguide

I try to change white background color in segment if **UISegmentedControl** gets focus.
Please look the folowing screenshot: 
[image]

And I need to change this white background color into clear. Something like this:
[image]

So I've created subclass of **UISegmentedControl** and ovveride **didUpdateFocus(in:with:)**
Look please the following screenshot:
[image]

But after that focus doesn't change anymore and I can't jump to next segment of **UISegmentedControl**.

I saw similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58449340/tvos-uisegmentedcontrol-focus-style-not-change), but I wasn't succeed of it.

It's tvOS and deployment target is 11.1.

Why is that? 
What is the better approach to change background color when focused?
Please help me.

Comment: if I use `super.didUpdateFocus(in: context, with: coordinator)`, then focus engine works, but segment in segmented control is highlight with white color like in first screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this problem by replacing `UISegmentControl` to `UICollectionView`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I misunderstood your question, but have you tried to change segmentControl.selectedSegmentTintColor property?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way (at initialization phase):

```
 segment.selectedSegmentTintColor = .clear
```

here segment: UISegmentedControl

Comment: doesn't help it